# sh-3.2 double vs quadruple backslash

Tags: bash, shell, escaping, sh, backslash

I'm on OS X 10.11.5, and I have a `/bin/bash` on my system with version 3.2.57. The `/bin/sh` reports the same thing, suggesting that `/bin/sh` is really bash 3.2.

My `/bin/sh` exhibits some weird behaviour: `echo \\` gives a single backslash (as expected), but `echo \\\\` *also* gives `\` as output, and you need 6 backslashes to get two as output. Demonstration:

```
>> /bin/bash
~$ echo \\
\
~$ echo \\\\
\\
~$ echo \\\\\\
\\\
~$ exit

>> /bin/bash --posix
~$ echo \\
\
~$ echo \\\\
\\
~$ echo \\\\\\
\\\
~$ exit

>> /bin/sh
sh-3.2$ echo \\
\
sh-3.2$ echo \\\\
\
sh-3.2$ echo \\\\\\
\\
sh-3.2$ exit

>> /bin/sh --posix
sh-3.2$ echo \\
\
sh-3.2$ echo \\\\
\
sh-3.2$ echo \\\\\\
\\
sh-3.2$ exit

>> /bin/sh --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

>> /bin/bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Question: why doesn't `echo \\\\` give two backslashes as output in `/bin/sh`, while it does in `/bin/bash`?

More info:

```
sh-3.2$ echo \\
\
sh-3.2$ echo \\\\
\
sh-3.2$ echo \\\\\\
\\
sh-3.2$ echo \\\\\\\\
\\
sh-3.2$ echo \\\\\\\\\\
\\\
sh-3.2$ echo \\\\\\\\\\\\
\\\
```

Comment: I just tested it on a linux system, and there too I get the same difference between /bin/bash (4.3) and /bin/sh (actually /bin/dash, don't know which version?)

Comment: POSIX standard says for `echo`  *"if any of the operands contain a backslash ( '\' ) character, the results are implementation-defined.*".  `\\ ` is defined for XSI systems, but not ` \\\\ `, so it looks like good old "undefined behaviour".

Comment: See also (but not a duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30818982/posix-shell-backslash-confusion

Comment: @cdarke Ah good old implementation-defined behaviour! Fun fact: double quotes give the same problematic output, but *single* quotes make echo do the right thing.

Comment: In `bash`,  `shopt -s xpg_echo` then you get the XPG standard behaviour (which is different again!).

Comment: what is "the right thing"?

Comment: Turns out there is a `./configure` option when building `bash` called `--enable-xpg-echo-default`.  That sets `xpg_echo` on by default (instead of off), so distributions of the *same version* of bash could differ.  I guess its safe to say that if you want portable behaviour, don't use more than two backslashes together.

Comment: If you want portable behavior, don't use `echo` at all. Use `printf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing the difference between the POSIX and `bash` implementations of `echo`. In short, POSIX `echo` expands certain escaped characters, while `bash` does not treat a backslash specially *unless* you use the `-e` option. Also, `bash` uses the POSIX implementation when it runs as `sh`, or when you explicitly set the `xpg_echo` option to use the POSIX version.

```
# POSIX
$ echo 'a\nb'
a
b
# bash
$ echo 'a\nb'
a\nb
$ echo -e 'a\nb'
a
b
```

Single quotes are just a shorthand for escaping every character contained with in. Using explicit escaping instead of single quotes for all of the above:

```
# POSIX
$ echo \a\\\n\b
a
b
# bash
$ echo \a\\\n\b
a\nb
$ echo -e \a\\\n\b
a
b
```

Double quotes are similar to single quotes, except the shell first processes a very limited set of escaped characters first. This is because `$` is treated specially inside double quotes, indicating a parameter expansion. You can escape the `$` to prevent this, and you can escape a backslash to prevent *it* from escaping the following character. In all other cases, the backslash is treated literally and passed along to `echo`.

```
$ foo=5
$ echo "$foo"
5
$ echo "\$foo"
$foo
$ echo "\\$foo"
\5
$ echo "\\\$foo"
\$foo
$ echo "\t"
\t
```

With that out of the way, how does each shell create `echo \\\\`? First, both shells perform quote removal to eliminate quotations marks and escaping backslashes. The first backslash escapes the second, and the third escapes the fourth, leaving just a pair of literal backslashes as the argument to `echo`. The POSIX version of `echo` treats `\\` as a literal backslash, while the `bash` version treats `\\` as a pair of literal backslashes.